# Kafka messages are duplicated?

Tags: php, apache-kafka

I have an issue with `kafka` and `php` that I couldn't understand : I have 3 server with `php 7.4` , `php-rdkafka extension 4.0`, `kafka 2.12`.

Server 1 and 3 run code ok but server 2 get duplicate messages with the same source code.

**How could I check config or something in PHP code?**

Comment: check if the server 2 consumers have the same consumer group as 1 and 3

Comment: No, kafka server is independence  on every server.